# Laravel get user data with profile

Tags: php, laravel, merge

I have user and profile models with followers/following. What I want is to get the User data with the Profile data merged when calling Profile::followers. Now I only retrieve the profile data.

So I added the user() to Profile.php so I can call Profile::followers->user()... but no result. Can someone explain how to merge the User with Profile when calling the `following()` function?

**User.php model**

```
public function following()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

**Profile.php model**

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I came late but the correct way to get a user profile would be

```
$profile = Auth::user()->profile;
```

I don't know if this would help, using `Auth::user()` you get to fetch the current user and since you have a relationship with the profile you can call the `profile()` public function without the braces.

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: The question is a year old, so yes you're late. There's no indication in the question that they're using authentication of any sort, and this doesn't answer the question of "What I want is to get the User data with the Profile data merged when calling Profile::followers."